# Licensing applications inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, licensing

I have an application that runs on a JBoss server host name and mac id based license. 
I have ported that application runs on a JBoss-Wildfly docker container in Windows 7 through Oracle Virtualbox. Now I need the same license which is based on the Windows machine's host and mac id to work in docker. 
How best to achieve this ? 
Also, please let me know of this is the best licensing strategy for this approach.